# как предусмотреть добавление в базу данных строки которая состоит из пробелов

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть строка которую я получаю из инпута, через метод $_POST, и перед тем как ее добавить в базу данных я делаю проверку, где хочу что бы ее минимальная длина была 25 символов (`if (mb_strlen($line) < 25) {// не добавляю} else {// добаляю}`), и только тогда я ее добавляю в таблицу баз данных. Но как мне предусмотреть то, что она может состоять из пробелов?

Comment: http://php.net/trim

Answer (score -2, accepted):

грубо говоря как-то так:

```
$string = '   какая то    строка      с  повторяющимися пробелами   ';
$pattern = '/([\s]+)/i';
$replacement = ' ';
$cleanString = trim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string));

var_dump($cleanString);
```

Comment: Спасибо, видно что профи в PHP : )